# Share an Inline Message link with User Conversation via Telegram Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I'm using [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) and I Have an inline Keyboard, How Can I Share a link When a user click on that Inline Link?
I need to Choose an Conversation and
after that paste this link in that Conversation:

(telegram.me/my_bot?start)

```
    const iopts = {
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [
                [{
                    text: `Share This Bot to Your Friends`,
                    url: `telegram.me/my_bot?start`
                }]
            ]
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `switch_inline_query` instead of `url`, see following example:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]